# Prove that $a_n=a_pn^p+a_{p-1}n^{p-1}+a_{p-2}n^{p-2}+\ldots+a_0$ converges to plus or minus infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergence-operator

Prove that: the sequence {$a_n$} diverges to plus or minus infinity if 
$$a_n=a_pn^p+a_{p-1}n^{p-1}+a_{p-2}n^{p-2}+\ldots+a_0$$ with $p$ in natural natural numbers, and $a_i$ in real numbers. Also given is that $a_p$ doesn't equal $0$.

This is an exercise I found in my Analysis 1 book. The chapter is mainly about convergence of sequences. This section in particular focuses on sequences that diverge to infinity.

I've tried a ratio test, that is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=\alpha$. It's a theorem in my book that if $\alpha>1$, then the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |{a_n}|=+\infty$

However when I calculate this limit, which I already have trouble with, I find the limit to be equal to 1. My book states that if $\alpha=1$, then ${a_n}$ may converge, diverge to plus or minus infinity or oscilate. This information isn't really helpful of course.

So I was wondering if anyone here could help me?

Also note that this is an introductory course on Analysis, the second chapter. That means that there should probably be a rather 'easy' solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One option: try to factor it as $a_n = n^p\left[a_p + \frac{a_{p-1}}{n} + \ldots + \frac{a_{0}}{n^p}\right]$ and consider what happens to every term inside the brackets when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: All terms inside the brackets except the first one would approach 0. Does that mean the limit goes to $n^p*a_p=\infty$ for large n? And does that limit actually prove that the sequence diverges? In my book it says that is {$a_n$} diverges to infinity, that the limit indeed goes to infinity. The converse, however, is never explicitly stated. How do I know that it is true, and that I may use it?

Comment: Exactly. Since the term in the brackets converges to $a_p$ we have that for large enough $n$ (for example) $\frac{a_p}{2}n^p \leq a_n \leq 2a_p n^p$ which would give that $a_n\to {\rm (sign~of~a_p)}\infty$.

Comment: ( Depending on how rigorous you need to be the result above can be proven rigorously using the $\epsilon-N$ definition of the limit. )

Comment: I appreciate your answer, yet I'm not entirely convinced, because certain theorems I don't know are used here. I think this is not what my book has in mind. But I understand the problem a bit more now. Thanks for your help.